# SQL query involving three tables and checking whether some result has entry in another table

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables in my SQL database as follows

#### `Users2`

```
UserID,
EID,
Name,
Email,
Department,
Enabled
```

#### `Sites`

```
SiteID,
SiteCode,
SiteName
```

#### `UserSites2`

```
UsersSitesID,
UserID,
SiteID
```

What I need to do is, given `EID` and `SiteID`, get a full row from the `Users2` table AND the `SiteID`, `SiteCode` and `SiteName` from the `Sites` table WHEN the `userID` of the retrieved record has an entry in the `UserSites2`

Example of expected result:

#### `Users2`

```
1, 12345, Me, me@email.com, Support, True
2, 12346, you, you@email.com, Service, True
```

#### `Sites`

```
1, 123, Regional HQ
2, 234, National HQ
```

#### `UserSites2`

```
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 2, 2
```

So given `EID` `12345` and `SiteID` `2` I should get the result

```
1, 12345, Me, me@email.com, Support, True, 2, 234, National HQ
```

and for `EID` `12346` and `SiteID` `1` I should get nothing

I know how to join `Users2` and `Sites` to get the full row I want but I don't understand how to make it depend on whether there is an entry in the lookup table for it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 12346 keys to 2, and 2,2 key to 3. So isn't that contrary to your penultimate sentence?

Comment: Mark, I guess he meant Site ID 1 ... seems like typing mistake to me.

Comment: Mark, yes I did mean SiteID 1 for that. Sorry I was trying to finish this question up before I left work tonight. Just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select u2.UserID, u2.EID, u2.Name, u2.Email, u2.Department, u2.Enabled, 
           s.SiteID, s.SiteCode, s.SiteName
    from users2 u2
        left outer join usersites us on u2.UserID = us.UserID 
        left outer join sites s on s.SiteID = us.SiteID 
    where u2.EID = 12345  and us.SiteID = 2
```

I have tested this. It will give you no records if it is not mapped in UserSites. So for EID 12346 and SiteID 1 you will get nothing.

Comment: I originally attempted to do this with INNER JOINS and my query looks almost exactly like this with that 1 exception. What I was getting was # of identical rows returned when SiteID = 1 and there was # entries in the UserSites2 Table with the same UserID. I am still learning teh differences between the JOINS. I can't wait to try this out when I get back to work. Thank you.

Comment: Well I couldn't wait so I recreated my tables here at home and this is definitely giving me exactly what I want. Thank you Rashmi.

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like this:

```
select col1,col2,.....from Users, Sites, UserSites 
where Users.eid = 12345 and Sites.siteid = 2 
  and users.user_id = userSites.userid 
  and sites.siteis = usersites.siteid
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to specifically list the joins where possible. I believe something like this would work:

```
select u2.UserID, u2.EID, u2.Name, u2.Email, u2.Department, u2.Enabled,
       s.SiteID, s.SiteCode, s.SiteName
from Users2 u2 join UserSites2 us2 on u2.UserID=us2.UserID 
     join sites s on us2.SiteID=s.SideID
where u2.EID=<eid> and 
      us2.SiteID=<siteid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i know how to join Users2 and Sites to get the full row I want, but I don't understand how to make it depend on wether there is an entry in the lookup table for it.

Using a LEFT JOIN means there might not be a supporting record, based on the join criteria.  Where records are missing, you'll see null in appropriate column.  If you want to only return rows based on the criteria, use a [INNER] JOIN.  Here's a [good link](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) showing the differences between JOINs and it includes UNIONs.

Here's your query:

```
SELECT u.userid,
       u.eid,
       u.name,
       u.email,
       u.department,
       u.enabled,
       s.siteid,
       s.sitecode,
       s.sitename
  FROM USERS2 u
  JOIN USERSITES2 us ON us.userid = u.userid
  JOIN SITES s ON s.siteid = us.siteid
 WHERE u.eid = ?
   AND us.siteid = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for that link Ponies. I am learning and every little bit helps.